# Why do I get two different bearer tokens in two different situations? Azure Active Directory (also microsoft blockchain workbench)

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication, azure-blockchain-workbench

trying to under something in Azure Active Directory.
I am trying to understand why I don't get the same bearer token when using the same user in these two situations:

1) By going to this blog post:
http://blog.pomiager.com/post/using-rest-api-in-azure-workbench-blockchain

I downloaded the project and the only thing that matters is that there is a sign in for an azure active directory. I sign in with my correct account and when debugging I can see my bearer token.

2) When I am inside my microsoft workbench app I go to inspect on chrome and in the network I can actually see the bearer token

these 2 bearer tokens are different although I do these 2 actions at the same time. The bearer token on the second option is the correct bearer token that lets me get access to my blockchain workbench app. I want to make actions on my microsoft workbench app when I sign in to my user.

How can I receive the correct bearer token?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The tokens you see are Jwt tokens. they will be unique everytime with limited validity (in case it gets compromised) but azure ad can validate them. on very high level if you are using azure ad open id connect authentication flow then you will be getting access_token (use to access api) and id_token(use to access user basic info) . you will always use access token to access api resources for which token is generated however in certian cases where you client is requesting token for its own backend then you may require id token.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens